# How to assure chief guest would attend event?

Tags: offices, events

I'am part of organising committee in my office, my duties include arranging chief guest for the event. Also i have contacted well known personality to attend event.
He has assured to be the chief guest for the day.

> How can i assure he would attend the event ?

*unsure if this is the right place for this query, im confused and would appreciate any thoughts from your experience.*

Comment: By telling him that it is very important for you to know that he will really attend, picking him up from the airport or any other place he would arrive traveling and generally making it as comfortable as possible for him?

Comment: thank you @skymningen for your thoughts, but what if he could not make up for the event ? also there is a session by chief guest for attendees, i assume i should keep ready with an alternative so as to make up the task and not to get embarassed

Comment: Don't assume, ask your boss if you are supposed to have an alternative set up. (Although, who would agree to be an "alternative chief guest"?)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with navigating the workplace.

Comment: If you make sure the guest is aware that they are the Guest of Honor, then they are much more likely to attend, or tell you that they cannot guarantee their attendance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your people contact his people. Contracts are signed, deposits are paid. It's very unlikely that you would discuss the minutiae of a personal appearance with the personality themselves.

Be aware that the contract will generally come with riders, e.g accommodation, travel, meals, product tables, technical specs such as microphones, etc.; it's much more than a simple "Can you come and have dinner with us, perhaps say a few words".

Once you get something in writing, the personality WILL attend (barring serious events like illness etc). If they do not, the contract will have the penalties detailed in there, and word starts getting around that this person is not reliable. Reputation is everything in the after-dinner speaking world, so you can be sure that they'll do everything they can to make sure you're happy with their performance.